# What is the status of exporting aurelia custom elements to web components?

Tags: aurelia

What is the status of exporting aurelia custom elements to web components?
I can see that there has been some work done on https://github.com/aurelia/web-components but there is no documentation present and it only states "soon".

How will it work? When should we expect it? And most importantly, Is it worth looking into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is dependent on the browsers implementing the v1 spec and/or someone creating a polyfill for the v1 spec. Most of the implementation of our plugin is done, pending testing against one or both of the above.